# Zend Lucene Search - Illegal Character problems

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, special-characters

How do I fix this error?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string
Filename: Common/Utf8.php
Line Number: 77

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string
Filename: Lucene/Field.php
Line Number: 222
```

These are the characters that I inputted.

```
ŸeÈ╬fý↔5ƒ1
```

and I tried saving into a lucene field.

P.S.

The input was processed using this code

```
htmlentities($input, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

I am using PHP 5.2.17 and Zend Framework 1.12.0

Comment: try process: iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input)); - it works for me, but I cannot test it now...

Comment: I would prefer a solution that cleans up the input rather than editing Zend files

Comment: That is solution for clean up input before adding to a Zend file.

Comment: Here are my results

(1) your iconv code then htmlentities = ŸeÈ???fý↔5ƒ1
(2) your iconv only = ?,e?????f? 1/2 ???5AE?1
(3) htmlentities then your iconv = ŸeÈ???fý↔5ƒ1

Comment: Than check supported encoding of Lucene http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.search.lucene.best-practice.html#zend.search.lucene.best-practice.encoding